# FactoryGirl setting wrong time for Rails model time attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

Given an ActiveRecord model with the schema,

```
create_table "foos", id: :serial, force: :cascade do |t|
  t.date "date"
  t.time "time"
# ...
```

and a `Foo` factory from FactoryGirl,

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :foo do
    date Date.today
    time Time.new(2001, 9, 11)
# ...
```

and an rspec model spec using a shoulda-matcher,

```
it { is_expected.to have_attributes(
      date: Date.today,
      time: Time.new(2001, 9, 11),
# ...
```

the test fails,

```
-:time => 2001-09-11 00:00:00.000000000 -0700,
+:time => 2000-01-01 08:00:00.000000000 +0000,
```

because the subject under test has a `time` attribute whose value is `2000-01-01 08:00:00.000000000 +0000`.

Why isn't FactoryGirl using the time value `Time.new(2001, 9, 11)` as specified in the factory?

Comment: `date` and `time` are dreadful names for fields - liable to clash with reserved words all over the place

Comment: I know. So is "foos," if you get my meaning.

Comment: no, `foos` is fine, it won't mess with any reserved words, and makes your example clear. Your field-name choices (if they're not real names) are obfuscating your example :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible because a `time` field disregards the date portion of the data stored in the DB. So your test would need to test that the `hhmmss` of the field matched your expectation - but you're also checking the `yymmdd`, and looks like zone's getting in on the act too.